# Javascript select radio button change php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<p>Until: <input value="<?php echo until_3months();?>" type="text" name="until"/></p>
                <input type="radio" name="unt" id="3" value="3" checked="checked">3 months
                <input type="radio" name="unt" id="6" value="6">6 months
                <input type="radio" name="unt" id="12" value="12">12 months
```

I want when user check 3/6/12 months from radios to change my php function to until_3months() / until_6months() / until_12months(). I thing this is not posible, so i can change value without php function, just javascript. My php function calculate 3/6/12 months from now in future. Something like warranty available until +3 / +6 / +12 months from now, i dont know how to replace this in javascript:

```
function until_3months(){
            $time = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
            $final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 month", $time));
            return $final;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't alter how PHP functions through javascript interaction, as the javascript has no way of talking to the PHP code unless you make an AJAX request to the server and ask for the value that way. However an AJAX request would be overkill for something like this and is not needed.

What you want to do is calculate your values and attach them to your HTML.

```
<p>Until: <input id="date-text-field" value="" type="text" name="until"/></p>
<input class="date-radio-button" data-date="<? echo until_3months(); ?>"  type="radio" name="unt" id="3" value="3" checked="checked">3 months 
<input class="date-radio-button" data-date="<? echo until_6months(); ?>"  type="radio" name="unt" id="6" value="6">6 months
<input class="date-radio-button" data-date="<? echo until_12months(); ?>" type="radio" name="unt" id="12" value="12">12 months
```

With those values set, you can now use those values in javascript (using JQuery) like so:

```
$('.date-radio-button').click(function(){
    $('#date-text-field').val($(this).attr('data-date'));
});
```

When a user clicks a radio button with the class 'date-radio-button' the text field '#date-text-field' will be updated with the data-date value that was attached to the radio button.